# Safari only: Refused to connect to ... because it does not appear in the connect-src directive of the Content Security Policy

Tags: google-chrome, google-analytics, safari, content-security-policy

When using Google Analytics, I'm getting the following error from Safari 13.1 but not from Chrome:

```
Refused to connect to https://www.google-analytics.com/j/collect?XYZ
because it does not appear in the connect-src directive of the Content Security Policy.
```

My application doesn't try to connect to `www.google-analytics.com`, but it downloads a script from `www.googletagmanager.com` which in turn downloads a script from `www.google-analytics.com`.

My CSP are configured as follows:

- `script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' data: www.google-analytics.com www.googletagmanager.com www.google.com www.gstatic.com`
- `connect-src 'self'`

So as Safari says, I don't have `google-analytics` in `connect-src`, but that doesn't seem to be a problem for Chrome.

Is my CSP wrong (and Chrome is being too permissive) or is this a bug in Safari?

Comment: In Chrome, does the script from `www.googletagmanager.com` try to fetch a script from `www.google-analytics.com`? It’s possible the Safari behavior follows a different code path than in Chrome. But anyway, if a document has a `connect-src 'self'` directive and any script the document has loaded tries to make a request (using fetch or XHR) for a resource at any other origin, the browser must block that request. So the Safari behavior is correct. But the Chrome behavior could also be correct, if it turns out that in Chrome the code isn’t making any scripted request to `www.google-analytics.com`.

Comment: I noticed today that even in Chrome I get the error, but not every time: I loaded the page and got the error, I reloaded it and didn't get the error. I even reloaded it clearing the cache and in an incognito window and the error didn't appear again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Safari is right. [Chrome is being too permissive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src):

> The HTTP Content-Security-Policy (CSP) script-src directive specifies valid sources for JavaScript.

Note that this statement is not qualified.

Chrome also violates other postulates of CSP. For example, `blocked-uri` for different origins [requires that the URI path is stripped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only#Violation_report_syntax), but Chrome doesn't do that and Safari does.

At this point in time Safari seems to be more compliant/strict than Chrome, but in any case you should go by the stricter browser because, well, you don't really have a choice...